# Clang thread safety annotation and shared capabilities

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl, clang, clang++

The following code is generating one warning when I use clang [thread annotations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html). I am trying to wrap `boost::shared_mutex` and `boost::shared_lock`. How can I express that this lock is a shared lock using the thread annotations?

**source code:**

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include "boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp"

class __attribute__((shared_capability("mutex"))) BoostSharedMutex {
public:
  boost::shared_mutex &getNativeHandle() { return m_mutex; }
private:
  mutable boost::shared_mutex m_mutex;
};

class __attribute__((scoped_lockable)) MutexSharedLock {
public:
    explicit MutexSharedLock(BoostSharedMutex &mutex) __attribute__((acquire_shared_capability(mutex)))
        : m_lock(mutex.getNativeHandle()) {}
    ~MutexSharedLock() __attribute__((release_shared_capability())) = default;

private:
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> m_lock;
};


int main() {
  BoostSharedMutex mutex;
  MutexSharedLock lock(mutex);
}
```

**clang output:**

```
clang++-3.6 --std=c++11 -Wall -Wthread-safety /tmp/foo.cpp -lboost_system
/tmp/foo.cpp:25:5: warning: releasing mutex 'lock' using shared access, expected exclusive access [-Wthread-safety-analysis]
    }
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

EDIT: this compiles but seems wrong. Is it a problem on my side?

```
#include <mutex>
#include "boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp"

class __attribute__((shared_capability("mutex"))) BoostSharedMutex {
public:
  boost::shared_mutex &getNativeHandle() { return m_mutex; }
private:
  mutable boost::shared_mutex m_mutex;
};

class __attribute__((scoped_lockable)) MutexSharedLock {
public:
    explicit MutexSharedLock(BoostSharedMutex &mutex) __attribute__((acquire_capability(mutex))) // changed  from acquired_shared_capability
        : m_lock(mutex.getNativeHandle()) {}
    ~MutexSharedLock() __attribute__((release_capability())) = default; // changed from release_shared_capability

private:
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> m_lock;
};

BoostSharedMutex mutex;
int locked_variable __attribute__((guarded_by(mutex)));

int main() {
  MutexSharedLock lock(mutex);
  std::cout << locked_variable << std::endl; // ok, guarded variable is only read
  locked_variable = 42; // no warning while writing in the guarded variable while only holding a non-exclusive lock?
}
```

Comment: `m_foo` doesn't seem to be relevant here (the warning appears even without that STL container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several combinations, this seems to work:

```
#include <mutex>
#include "boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp"

class __attribute__((capability("mutex"))) BoostSharedMutex {
public:
  boost::shared_mutex &getNativeHandle() { return m_mutex; }
private:
  mutable boost::shared_mutex m_mutex;
};

class __attribute__((scoped_lockable)) MutexSharedLock {
public:
    explicit MutexSharedLock(BoostSharedMutex &mutex) __attribute__((acquire_shared_capability(mutex)))
        : m_lock(mutex.getNativeHandle()) {}
    ~MutexSharedLock() __attribute__((release_capability())) = default;

private:
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> m_lock;
};

class __attribute__((scoped_lockable)) MutexLock {
public:
    explicit MutexLock(BoostSharedMutex &mutex) __attribute__((acquire_capability(mutex)))
        : m_lock(mutex.getNativeHandle()) {}
    ~MutexLock() __attribute__((release_capability())) = default;

private:
    std::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> m_lock;
};

BoostSharedMutex mutex;
int locked_variable __attribute__((guarded_by(mutex)));

int main() {
  {
    MutexSharedLock lock(mutex);
    std::cout << locked_variable << std::endl;
    // locked_variable = 42; -- triger a error as expected
  }
  {
    MutexLock lock(mutex);
    std::cout << locked_variable << std::endl;
    locked_variable = 42;
  }
}
```

I would be curious to hear why the `MutexSharedLock` should use `acquire_shared_capability` but release with `release_capability` ...

(I will let the question open in case anyone can confirm the code is correct now)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unlock_function` instead of `release_shared_capability`.

Same true also for `try_acquire_capability`/`try_acquire_shared_capability` - they just don't work, but previous `exclusive_trylock_function`/`shared_trylock_function` works well.
M.b. it is bug in clang.